# Jest React - Test suite failed to run, Cannot find module 'react-dotenv'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I used Create React App to make a new project, and now i try to implement each feature i will need.

I am facing an issue i dont understand while trying to configure jest with reactjs.
One my node_modules, `react-dotenv` break jest test.

[image]

If i try to copy/past the issue line `import env from 'react-dotenv';` directly in the root tested file `Login.tsx` there is no error.
I tried to configure `moduleNameMapper` and search around without success..

I dont understand the problem, what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was missing `mocks` and `transformIgnorePatterns`
Didn't really make `transformIgnorePatterns` working using:

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!react-dotenv)"],
```

but the `mocks`

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^.+\\.(css|scss)$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/CSSStub.config.js',
  'react-dotenv': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-dotenv.tsx'
},
```

did the job.

Comment: Hello, where did you add the moduleNameMapper and the transformIgnorePatterns, at which script? Having the same issue here :/

Comment: I add these in a jest config file  

`module.exports = {
    ...
    moduleNameMapper: {
        ...
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        ...
    ]
    ...
}`

and add use this configuration file when launching jest
`node jest --config=./config/jest.config.js`